# How to pass data from angluar component to angular layout component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a page where the contract has some basic information display in app-contract and I have a menu with different taps each tab contains some information about the contract shipping the components needed etc. I just click on a tab and it load contract details example the shipping information of the contract. However my issue is that when I do a search in the search tab the `<app-contract></app-contract>` fields are not updating for example the contract number remains the same. I am not sure what to use emitter viewchild etc to get the a `<app-contract></app-contract>` component to be up to date.

I have this page
[image: Contract page]

Here is a visual representation of angular component structure

[image: my structure]

here is the relevant code for the contract search. Has you can see I have added a       `change: EventEmitter<Contract> = new EventEmitter<Contract>();` in the search component `<app-contract-search></app-contract-search>` I am not sure what to do after words with it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract-search',
  templateUrl: './contract-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contract-search.component.css']
})
export class ContractSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  public contractNumber: string;
  public contract: Contract;
  public searchValue: string;


  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<Contract> = new EventEmitter<Contract>();

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService, private contractService: ContractService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // First get the contract id from the current route.
    const url = window.location.href;
    var parts = url.split('/', 6);

    this.contractNumber = parts[4];
    this.searchValue = this.contractNumber;

    console.log("Contract Id form url : " + this.contractNumber);

    this.GetContract(this.contractNumber);
  }


  GetContract(id: string) {
    this.contractService.getContractByContractNumber(Number(id)).subscribe(result => {
      this.contract = result;
      this.change.emit(this.contract);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  search() {

    this.contractService.checkIfContractExists(this.searchValue).subscribe(contract => {
      if (contract) {
        console.log("contract " + this.searchValue + " found");
        this.GetContract(contract.contractNumber.toString());
        this.toastr.success("Success","The contract is being loaded!");
        this.router.navigate(['/contract', contract.contractNumber, 'search']);
      }
      else {
        console.log("contract " + this.searchValue + " NOT found");
        this.toastr.error("Error", "The contract number was not found!");
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });

  }
}
```

And then here in the `<app-contract></app-contract>` component is where I want to get the update contract information here. Is there a way I can listen to the event emitter here?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract',
  templateUrl: './contract-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contract-layout.component.css']
})
export class ContractComponent implements OnInit {

  public contract: Contract;
  public contractId: number;

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient,
              private contractService: ContractService ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    // First get the product id from the current route.
    const routeParams = this.router.snapshot.paramMap;
    this.contractId = Number(routeParams.get('contractId'));

    console.log("Contract Id form url : " + this.contractId);

    this.GetContractByNumber(this.contractId);

  }

  GetContractByNumber(number: number) {
    this.contractService.getContractByContractNumber(number).subscribe(result => {
      this.contract = result;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the layout of my contract

```
<p *ngIf="!contract"><em>{{'HtmlElement.Loading' | translate}}</em></p>

<div *ngIf="contract">

  <h2>Contract details {{contract.contractNumber}}</h2>
  <form action="" id="GeneralForm" method="post">
     //Here is the form Form Contract details
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
        <br>
        <input id="btnSalvar" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="card">
    <p class="card-header">
      <app-contract-menu></app-contract-menu>
    </p>
    <div class="card-body">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are using observables for sharing data, that is very good practice, I suggested an answer which is simpler but it seems it will require changes from your side , have you tried to inject ChangeDetectorRef in your app component , then call its method detectChanges after you bind the contract to result at the observable subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose another option. The idea is to use an `Observable` `Subject` in your `ContractService`.

So in your `ContractService` declare something like:

```
private _newContractSearched = new Subject<Contract>();
newContractSearched = this._newContractSearched.asObservable();

public triggerNewContractSearched(contract: Contract){
    this._newContractSearched.next(contract);
}
```

Then in `ContractSearchComponent`, every time you search:

```
this.contractService.triggerNewContractSearched(contract);
```

And finaly in `ContractComponent` just subscribe to that observable:

```
this.contractService.newContractSearched.subscribe(contract: Contract => {
    // Here you have the contract object
});
```

Maybe this is not the best solution, but should work.

Comment: Where in ContractComponent do I use this.contractService.newContractSearched.subscribe(contract: Contract => {
    // Here you have the contract object
}); do I put this code in ngOnInit?

Comment: In ngOnInit function

Comment: But remember that you have to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy. If you don't unsubscribe, it will subscribe every time ContractComponent is instantiated.
To achieve that, you need a new variable and do something like `this.sub = this.contractService.newContractSearched.subscribe(cont...` and then in the ngOnDestroy do `this.sub.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Yes I think your solution would be the best for what I want to achieve but where does this.sub come from?

Comment: I belive the sub is this   public sub: Subscription; ?

Comment: Exactly, just declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Your component has been created once and since it is not getting any new inputs, nothing is forcing it to be rerendered

1- Move your App Contract component onInit event code to OnChanges event instead

2- Inject the contract as an input in your component, so when ever contract changes the onChanges event will be called

3- You are emitting the contract from search using event emitter therefore you can grab it in html and pass it to the app contract component as input

3- Your Html should look like that

```
<app-contract-search (change)= "contract=$event"></app-contract-search>
<app-contract [contract]="contract"></app-contract>
```

4- Your new App Component ts code

```
public [input] contract: Contract;
```

5- you don't need to do getContract method or any further subscriptions because you will be duplicating the logic

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am not sure who to accomplish step 1 and step 2?

Comment: I reedit my answer, basically the idea is the output on one component "search one in this case" is the input of the other "app component", you are already using event emitter in search component so it can be captured in the html binding since this is an output ,  then it will act an input to the app component via input binding in HTML /ts changes accordingly

Comment: The thing is the <app-contract-search></app-contract-search> is never user in my case since I have the <router-outlet></router-outlet> that take care of the tabs in my sub menu.

Comment: should i but the (change)= "contract=$event" inside the <router-oulet> like so <router-outlet (change)= "contract=$event" ></router-outlet>?

Comment: No that wont work ,  we assumed your html has no router-outlet , try my other suggested answer with changedetectorRef, I honestly feel you are overcomplicating your app, you are using event emitters that are of no use and I am not even sure you need outer outlet in the first place, but it is what it is

Answer (score 1):

You can alter you app component ts to the following

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-contract',
 templateUrl: './contract-layout.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./contract-layout.component.css']
 })
 export class ContractComponent implements OnInit {

 public contract: Contract;
 public contractId: number;

 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient,
          private contractService: ContractService, private ChangeDetectorRef 
          changeDetector) { }


 ngOnInit(): void {

 // First get the product id from the current route.
  const routeParams = this.router.snapshot.paramMap;
  this.contractId = Number(routeParams.get('contractId'));

  console.log("Contract Id form url : " + this.contractId);

  this.GetContractByNumber(this.contractId);

}

GetContractByNumber(number: number) {
  this.contractService.getContractByContractNumber(number).subscribe(result => {
  this.contract = result;
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();// this will force rerender your component 
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
});
}}
```

Comment: I think the app-contract -search trigger the rerender ot the app-contract-component? Since in my case the ContractSearchComponent is the one where GetContractByNumber is triggered the GetContractByNumber in ContractComponent is only triggered once when the page is loaded. Is there a way that the ContractSearchComponent can trigger the rerender of the ContractComponent ?

Comment: Yes this is the idea but since you are using router-outlet you eliminated this possibility therefore you have two options ,, ditch router outlet and adapt my first answer, give this answer a trial and check if your issue has been resolved

Comment: Ok I will to more research I think about it. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

in `app-contract` component

```
<app-contract-search (change)="GetContractByNumber($event.number)"><app-contract-search>
```

Comment: This will work too, but he is already emitting the contract as output why the need to go back to fetch it one more time with Id, wouldn't be better just to pass the contract as input the app component

Comment: The thing is the <app-contract-search></app-contract-search> is never used in my case since I have the <router-outlet></router-outlet> that take care of the tabs in my sub menu.  I have edit my question to show the html part, But thank you for your help